# Can't make request to UTF-8 link using node.js and "request" module

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, request, html-escape-characters

For some reason, I have a problem with "request" module.

```
var options = {
    protocol: "https",
    host: "euw.api.pvp.net",
    pathname: "/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" + name,
    search: "api_key=api-key-deleted"
};
var riotURL = url.format(options);

request(riotURL, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        //doing someting
    }
});
```

And then it goes weird. If name is simple, like "Dager", "hi mom" and so one, my app doing fine. But when I try to put names like "növentaynueve", "Mìnou" - my request return 404 response.

I managed to get full response text: http://pastebin.com/8Vra1i4X. And I can't understand what happened. All links in response are correct. But it looks like request module instead of sending request to

```
https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/n%C3%B6ventaynueve?api_key=api-key-deleted
```

sends request to

```
https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/n%EF%BF%BDventaynueve?api_key=api-key-deleted
```

But why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem with `encodeURI()` function.

And funny thing: on Debian, it works even without `encodeURI()`. But on Windows 10 not. Both source files are UTF-8.